# Nextcord "Module not Found"

Tags: python, discord, nextcord

again.

I've had this particular annoying issue for a some time now, it's regarding the Python "Module Not Found" for "Nextcord", i have a few versions of python installed to make sure it isn't a version problem but that may also be a double edge sword.

I've made sure that Nextcord is installed on all of the versions so that there cannot be a possibility of the module being missing.

I've asked around and i've tried a few things.
I've already done these troubleshooting steps:

- Uninstalled and re-installed all python versions, at some point ran one at a time.
- Made sure it ran the propper version that nextcord supports [3.8+].
- Removed all my bot files, i.e the entire folder.
- Re-did all of the steps to set up the bot.
- Made sure it's not a permissions issue with windows.
- Ran the code as administrator, downloaded nextcord as an administrator.

At this point i am just lost, i have no idea what i can do next, i will try my best to be active here so i can respond quickly to any answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well i found my own solution, it appears that when i re-installed the project folder i managed to forget the last crucial step of the bot which was

`(bot-env) C:\Users\mark.adelsberg\Desktop\Bot>pip install -U nextcord`

I kept downloading nextcord in the bot directory and forgot to run it as the bot-env.